# Why is there a period after the roman numeral in a royal title?

Tags: numbers, typography, periods, ordinal-numbers

In *The Wealth of Nations*, whenever a royal name appears, there is a period after the roman numeral. Why is this, and why has the practice been discontinued? If you search [this online copy](http://www2.hn.psu.edu/faculty/jmanis/adam-smith/Wealth-Nations.pdf) for a royal name ("George", for example) you can see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Relevant post on Latin SE: https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/4240/9 It seems periods after roman numerals may indicate ordinal numbers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the [1949](http://books.google.com/books?id=K9D8dUsxbxQC&pg=PA85&dq=period%20%22after%20roman%20numerals%22&hl=en&ei=wreuTsijIIjMtAaEv4CxDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=7&ved=0CFAQ6AEwBjgU#v=onepage&q&f=false) *Bibliographical description and cataloguing* by John Duncan Cowley:

> The earliest printers used roman numerals more often than arabic and usually divided a long numeral by means of stops, thus:
>
> > M.ccccc.xvij.
> >     M. v. C. xxvij.
> >     M | CCCCC. | XLII.
> >     M. D. xliii
>
> They also habitually printed a stop *before* as well as after roman numerals and occasionally adopted the same practice with arabic numbers, e.g.
>
> > The price of the whole boke (.xl.s.) whych boke conteynyth .iii. grete volumes.
> >     ... die .x. Februarii.
> >     . . . the .xxii. day of Deceber in the .xix | yere of the reyngne of oure so | uerayne lorde kinge Henry | the .viii. |
> >     . . . Anno .1568.
>
> Even when a contracted word precedes the numeral, a stop between the two as often as not belongs to the numeral:
>
> > . . . Anno Dom .M.D. xv.
>
> Sometimes the end of a line serves instead of a preceding or succeeding stop, but not always; in fact the preceding stop may be separated from the numeral by the line-ending, e.g.
>
> > . . . al .xviii. an du | tresuictorieux et so | ueraigne roy | Henry le. | viii.|

Check the book for an example from 1510 that illustrates how careful you must be reading these periods; if you're not careful you may read 1st April 1517 instead of 26th March 1510.

Perhaps due to these complications, these practices were simplified over time. For example, an [1897](http://books.google.com/books?ei=HLyuTrOxNsyUswbNloHnAw&ct=result&id=24LnAAAAMAAJ&dq=stop%20%22after%20roman%20numerals%22&q=%20%22after%20roman%20numerals%22#search_anchor) *American Printer and Lithographer* says:

> It is also proper to use the period after Roman numerals, where the " th " is understood, as " Charles XII. of Sweden," rendered in reading aloud "Charles the Twelfth, of Sweden." The rule is an arbitrary one, since it is not carried out in the case of the Arabic numerals, as, for instance, Feb. 24 would never appear with a period after ...

This advice changed around 1900 and by [1920](http://www.archive.org/details/concisemanualofs00reedrich) *A Concise Manual of Style* says:

> Period. Omit period after roman numerals when used in such cases as Chapter I, Henry IV, Part VIII, etc.

Comment: IIRC ordinals are customarily written in German with a period after the numeral. I immediately wonder whether, like capitalising the first letter of nouns, this is an orthographic practice which has been retained in German but abandoned in English.

Comment: @ColinFine Interesting point, you could ask over at [German Language & Usage](http://german.stackexchange.com/)!

Comment: I don't think the 1920 Concise Manual of Style advice is actually a change from the 1897 quotation. Those are cases where the number is just a number, not an ordinal. In many languages, and formerly in English, the period was used after Roman numerals to signify the ordinal.

Comment: The ‘German’ way of writing ordinals is also used in all the Nordic languages (though I suspect Finnish only uses it as a borrowing from Swedish).

Comment: @Hugo This ["point"](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24390/ursprung-des-punktes-bei-ordinalzahlen) finally came up today at German Language SE (in German).

Comment: In Czech language use of period after any roman numeral is mandatory. Ordinary arabic numbers use period as well.