# Using ordinal indicators with Roman numerals

Tags: typography, ordinal-numbers, superscripts

Is the use of ordinal indicators with Roman numerals grammatical and if grammatical, is it unneeded? For instance:
She is in VIIth standard.
What about in case the ordinal indicator was written as a superscript?

Comment: See also [What decides how to read a Roman number in titles?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/339232), [Why is there a period after the roman numeral in a royal title?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46783)